# Strange bug in MacVim 7.4 and some others apps on MacBook Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, macvim

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93r14.jpg) (excuse me for bad quality)

Explanation: In full screen mode in MacVim 7.4 i see the background panel. 
I tried `set transparency=0` but it does not work, Is it good to see backpanel in fullscreen vim and some other apps?

Thank you.

PrintScreen [image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Some colors seem transparent and it's really annoying.